# Implementing Facebook App so that Android/iOS app can be easily generated

Tags: android, ios, facebook

Hey guys I'm creating a Facebook Application as my summer project and am very interested in making it accessible on mobile devices.  However I have been unable to access fb apps on my phone (android) both via the official FB app and by logging onto the website.  It seems that some Facebook applications have mobile apps too, and I was wondering whether:

- Were these appls written from scratch in a platform language such as Java or Objective-C or did they use some sort of wrapper application to wrap the existing Facebook app code?  A friend or mine is using the latter method to make an  android app after using flash to make it so I know this way exists!
- Are there any specific design issues I should consider if this is my aim?  Such as using a specific languages to make it?

Any pointers are appreciated!  Thanks for reading :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the [Mobile](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/) documentation you'll find that you have 3 options: Mobile Web, iOS and Android, and for each of them you'll find a tutorial.

It's hard to answer your question since you don't give too much info, for example what's the app you already have? is it strictly static or do you have a server side for it? What do you want to do in the mobile version? Is it just an interface to your existing app, or you want to recreate it in a mobile version?

Comment: Hey Nitzan - I followed the link you gave and actually found exactly what I was looking for!  It's something called PhoneGap which allows you to deploy the web application various platforms! Thanks!